# Save matplotlib figures as .pdf_tex

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, inkscape

In Inkscape, there is the possibility of saving pdf files along with generating pdf_tex files for automatic formatting into a Latex file.
This can be specified by checking a box after clicking on save and specifying the extension as `.pdf`.

I'm interested in directly saving, from my python script, matplotlib figures in that specific format.

Does this possibility exist or can it be done with some tricks?

Comment: [Those are the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCmYT.png) I see in inkscape. Which one of those are you refering to?

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough. You can open a file and when saving it as a pdf, there is an option for generating a .pdf_tex file along with the .pdf file

Answer (score 1):

An option is to export a pdf from matplotlib and then use inkscape programmatically, i.e. through the command line interface to let it create the desired format.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(x=[1,2], height=[3,4], label="Bar")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Label")
plt.title("title")

def savepdf_tex(fig, name, **kwargs):
    import subprocess, os
    fig.savefig("temp.pdf", format="pdf", **kwargs)
    incmd = ["inkscape", "temp.pdf", "--export-pdf={}.pdf".format(name),
             "--export-latex"] #"--export-ignore-filters",
    subprocess.check_output(incmd)
    os.remove("temp.pdf")


savepdf_tex(plt.gcf(), "latest")

plt.show()
```

Also note that matplotlib can save in the `pgf` format. It's definitely worth trying as an alternative to the above. See [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/pgf_preamble_sgskip.html), and append `plt.savefig("filename.pgf")` to it. In the latex code use `\input{filename.pgf}`.

Comment: The returns the error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 1):

### As matplotlib backend

I created a [matplotlib backend](https://github.com/fvarno/PDFTex) a few years ago specifically to support this feature. However, it is only compatible with older matplotlib versions and must be updated (I would appreciate any contributions).

### Directly from your script

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest [has already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52730744/9784436) this. However, if that solution fails, try it with `--export-filename` or `-o` instead of `--export-pdf`.